# desialize object in silverlight from server

Tags: c#, winforms, silverlight, wcf, serialization

I have a winform application (C# framework 2.0) which generates object information by serializung into xml files. these files I want to upload into the server in silverlight application (c# VS 2010). the silverlight application use the objects in the XML.

1. how to upload these files and store them in the server with silverlight.
2. how to deserialize these objects into silverlight code. (how to get the objects from the server.

please ATTACH CODE example.

10x!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you handling the comms yourself, since [Silverlight supports `XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), this should still be pretty easy; just use [Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

However, the easier option is probably to use a [web-service reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296254%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (or perhaps a web-reference) - since this will handle transferring the type-model (or rather: a shallow interpretation of the type=model) for you - in both directions.

Comment: @gln - it is your web-service; the MSDN link should point you in the direction...